# enrol_manual_enrol_users, vincular usuario a curso no Moodle via webservice

Tags: php, rest, moodle

Preciso criar um vinculo entre um usuario e um curso, gostaria de fazer isso utilizando webservice.

O moodle possui nativo a função enrol_manual_enrol_users para esse proposito, que possui como parametros obrigatórios o tipo de vinculo `roleid`, o id do usuário `userid` e o id do curso `courseid`.

Mas se eu tento utilizar o seguinte erro é retornado, e nada é inserido na tabela `mdl_role_assignments`

```json
    "debuginfo":"Missing required key in single structure: enrolments"
```

Mesmo com os três campos obrigatórios existindo na base do moodle.

```php
    /// Connection
    $token = 'ed874e6d9f52539e180f49f4d926d50f';
    $domainname = 'http://localhost/moodle';
    $functionname = 'enrol_manual_enrol_users';
    $restformat = 'json';

    //////// enrol_manual_enrol_users ////////

    /// Paramètres
    $enrolment = new stdClass();
    $enrolment->roleid = 5; //estudante(student) -> 5; moderador(teacher) -> 4; professor(editingteacher) -> 3;
    $enrolment->userid = 2;
    $enrolment->courseid = 5; 
    $enrolments = array( $enrolment);
    $params = array('enrolments' => $enrolments);

    print_r($params);

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    $serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction='.$functionname;
    require_once('./curl.php');
    $curl = new curl;
    //if rest format == 'xml', then we do not add the param for backward compatibility with Moodle < 2.2
    $restformat = ($restformat == 'json')?'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat:'';
    $resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
    print_r($resp);
```

Segue a lista de parametros aceitos por essa função

```php
    'roleid' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'Role to assign to the user'),
    'userid' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'The user that is going to be enrolled'),
    'courseid' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'The course to enrol the user role in'),
    'timestart' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'Timestamp when the enrolment start', VALUE_OPTIONAL),
    'timeend' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'Timestamp when the enrolment end', VALUE_OPTIONAL),
    'suspend' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'set to 1 to suspend the enrolment', VALUE_OPTIONAL)
```

Já fiz testes atribuindo valores para estes parametros opcionais, mas nada muda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não consegui fazer esta função do webservice funcionar, decidi criar o vinculo diretamente via banco.

Para isso adaptei as querys do blog [MoodleSQL](http://moodlesql.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/matricular-usuario-no-curso-do-moodle.html) nas seguintes funções (a implementação foi feita num componente do Joomla)

```
    public function moodleEnrolUsers($roleid, $userid, $courseid){
        require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/moodle.php';

        //getDatabaseOption retorna o objeto com as configurações de conexão com a base de dados externa
        $db = JDatabase::getInstance( MoodleHelper::getDatabaseOption() );

        // pega o id do contexto a partir do id do curso
        $contexto = $this->getMoodleContext($courseid);

        $assignment = new stdClass();
        $assignment->roleid = $roleid; //indica o tipo de vinculo que haverá entre o aluno e o curso
        $assignment->contextid= $contexto; //o id do contexto referencia indiretamente o curso
        $assignment->userid= $userid;


        $result = $db->insertObject('#__role_assignments', $assignment);

        //INSERT INTO mdl_role_assignments (roleid,contextid,userid) VALUES (?,?,?)
        return $result;

    }
```

`getMoodleContext()` retorna o `contextid` de um curso a partir de seu `courseid`

```
    //muitas tabelas não referenciam o curso diretamente pelo id, o fazem através da tabela de contexto
    public function getMoodleContext($courseid){
        require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/moodle.php';

        $db = JDatabase::getInstance( MoodleHelper::getDatabaseOption() );

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('id');
        $query->from('`#__context`');
        $query->where('contextlevel=50 AND instanceid='.$courseid);

        $db->setQuery($query);

        return $db->loadResult();
    }
```

Para abstrair o `roleid` criei também as seguintes funções

```
    public function vincularAluno($userid, $courseid){
        return $this->moodleEnrolUsers(5, $userid, $courseid);
    }

    public function vincularTutor($userid, $courseid){
        return $this->moodleEnrolUsers(4, $userid, $courseid);
    }

    public function vincularProfessor($userid, $courseid){
        return $this->moodleEnrolUsers(3, $userid, $courseid);
    }
```